# Ansible No Content Found in Repository

Tags: ansible, ansible-role, ansible-galaxy

I'm trying to import a role into Ansible galaxy but getting the error:

```
No content found in repository
```

Using:

```
ansible-galaxy import Dynatrace-Adam-Gardner Dynatrace-Plugin-Development-Ansible
```

This also fails via the galaxy website. I don't see what's wrong with my repo. It looks perfectly well structured to me.

```
https://github.com/Dynatrace-Adam-Gardner/Dynatrace-Plugin-Development-Ansible
```

Looking at an accepted role such as:

```
https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-apache
```

They both look similar to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible roles need at least /meta/main.yml and /tasks/main.yml folders + files.